# unable to run report server

Tags: sql, reporting

Can you shed some light on this issue with SQL report server(2012)? I can't run SQL report Server from SQL Report Server Configuration. The error message is "the server didn't respond in a timely fashion...." For that, I did modified service pipe timeout to binary 60000, but no luck. 
When in Event Viewer, the related error details is " Default domain failed to initialize"

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

Please read this MS KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2745448

In short The SSRS service checks for certificate revocation lists (CRL) and something is blocking your attempts (usually Windows Firewall).

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Your answer suggests a workable solution to the question is available via another website. The Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites [generally frowns on this type of answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) and consider revising your answer to include the steps required to resolve the issue. And don't forget to take the [site tour](http://serverfault.com/tour).

Comment: Hi I was not able to follow method#2, I can't find Local Group Policy under Computer Configuration ,inside gpedit.msc